octal escape sequences are not allowed in strict mode
import {
  createNft,
  fetchDigitalAsset,
  mplTokenMetadata,
} from "@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata";

import {
  airdropIfRequired,
  getExplorerLink,
  getKeypairFromFile,
} from "@solana-developers/helpers";

import { createUmi } from "@metaplex-foundation/umi-bundle-defaults";

import { Connection, LAMPORTS_PER_SOL, clusterApiUrl } from "@solana/web3.js";
import {
  generateSigner,
  keypairIdentity,
  percentAmount,
} from "@metaplex-foundation/umi";

const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("devnet"));

const user = await getKeypairFromFile();

await airdropIfRequired(
  connection,
  user.publicKey,
  1 * LAMPORTS_PER_SOL,
  0.5 * LAMPORTS_PER_SOL
);

console.log("Loaded user", user.publicKey.toBase58());

const umi = createUmi(connection.rpcEndpoint);
umi.use(mplTokenMetadata());

const umiUser = umi.eddsa.createKeypairFromSecretKey(user.secretKey);
umi.use(keypairIdentity(umiUser));

console.log("Set up Umi instance for user");

const collectionMint = generateSigner(umi);

const transaction = await createNft(umi, {
  mint: collectionMint,
  name: "My Collection",
  symbol: "MC",
  uri: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/solana-developers/professional-education/main/labs/sample-nft-collection-offchain-data.json",
  sellerFeeBasisPoints: percentAmount(0),
  isCollection: true,
});
await transaction.sendAndConfirm(umi);

const createdCollectionNft = await fetchDigitalAsset(
  umi,
  collectionMint.publicKey
);

console.log(
  `Created Collection ! Address is ${getExplorerLink(
    "address",
    createdCollectionNft.mint.publicKey,
    "devnet"
  )}`
);

octal escape sequences are not allowed in strict mode.
when I run npx esrun create-collection.ts I get the above error. I have tried with different node versions
This is NFT project from solana bootcamp.

You are likely getting an octal sequence in your console.log().
The problem might be because you are creating the NFT collection and immediately following it up with an RPC call to fetch the created account but the changes might not have been propagated throughout the whole network.
Try commenting out the digital asset fetch and running your script again.
// --- snip, remains the same as before

// const createdCollectionNft = await fetchDigitalAsset(
//  umi,
//  collectionMint.publicKey
// );

console.log(
    `Created collection ! Address is: ${getExplorerLink(
        "address",
        collectionMint.publicKey,
        "devnet"
    )}`
);

console.log("✅ Finished successfully!");

ref on encountered error -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Deprecated_octal_escape_sequence
